# Iterate over bash array

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to use the values of one array to point to values in another, but I can't figure it out. I think this is very basic. I'd like the file to yield one line associated with each of x, y, z as follows: x XValue, y Yvalue, Z Zvalue but I just get the first line.

```
#! /bin/bash
declare -a id
declare -A header

id=( x y z )

header[x]="X Value"
header[y]="Y Value"
header[z]="Z Value"

for ident in $id
do
    echo $ident ${header[${ident}]}
done
```

Comment: Change `$id` to `"${id[@]}"`.

Comment: Non-numeric indices only work in bash 4 or greater.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `${id[@]}` to indicate all elements of array `id`:

```
$ for i in "${id[@]}"; do echo "This is "${header["$i"]}""; done
This is X Value
This is Y Value
This is Z Value
```

While you are getting only the first element using `$id`:

```
$ for i in "$id"; do echo "This is "${header["$i"]}""; done
This is X Value
```